# System.Drawing memory leak within Parallel.ForEach(...)

Tags: c#, memory-leaks, task-parallel-library, system.drawing

I am processing a list of images with the System.Drawing classes. If I process the images within a normal foreach loop everything's fine but when I am looping over the images (with image I don't mean any disposable System.Drawing.Image isntances but sources (urls) for images) with Parallel.ForEach I run out of memory. My process gets bigger and bigger (> 1GB). The Graphic buffers don't seem to be released althoug I took care about releasing all resources. This can be confirmed by just switching to non parallel foreach(...). The process stays at about 60 MB.

Did you encounter such a problem?

```
        // memory "leak". process grows beyound 1GB to infinity
        Parallel.ForEach(urls, url =>
        {
            ImageResizer.DownloadAndResizeImage(url);
        });


        // no memory "leak"
        foreach (string url in urls)
        {
            ImageResizer.DownloadAndResizeImage(url);
        }
```

Comment: Well, since you've shown us *no* code, how do you expect us to help you?

Comment: By reading my question thoroughly? I think all information is in there, but I will add  some abstract code to my question although I doubt that it will help.

Comment: There are about 11 billion different ways to write code to interact with images in sequential and parallel ways. Some of these will leak memory, some will *appear* to leak memory, some will definitely not. We don't know what you've written. Try to create a *short* but *complete* example that *demonstrates* the problem, and add that code to your question. Frequently, in the course of trying to construct such an example, you'll uncover new clues that point to the problem.

Comment: Um... hello? Did the question just change from Parallel.Invoke to Parallel.ForEach??

Comment: Yes chagned form Parallel.Invoke to ForEach...my fault. Sorry.

Answer (score 3):

I would expect Parallel.Invoke to consume more memory while it's processing because it's attempting to process more than 1 image at a time.  Parallel.Invoke will also wait on all tasks to complete before it returns and because you say an "Out of Memory" error occurs, I'm guessing it never returns, so there's no way to know if a memory leak is occurring.

Try processing just two images with Parallel.Invoke and see if your memory goes back down to a known starting point when the process is finished.  If so, then no memory leak - you're simply trying to process more than your system can handle at one time.

If that's the case, try using Parallel.ForEach instead with a limit on the number of threads using MaxDegreeOfParallelism.

First thing I would try (provided you have 4 cores):

```
Parallel.ForEach( 
    urls, 
    new ParallelOptions { MaxDegreeOfParallelism = 4 }, 
    url => { ImageResizer.DownloadAndResizeImage(url); } 
);
```

Edit:

Well, the question appears to have changed from Parallel.Invoke to Parallel.ForEach with some added code :), but that shouldn't change my answer much because Parallel.ForEach will wait until all tasks have been completed as well.

I would guess that the method DownloadAndResizeImage() is likely the culprit, and not so much Parallel.  In order to CORRECTLY process requests asynchronously, it takes a considerable amount of development using the low level Networking APIs.  Using Microsoft's WebClient or HttpWebRequest objects have known bottlenecks that limit the number of requests that can be made asynchronously through multithreading.  I know this, because I recently tried to the same thing and ended up writing the socket layer myself.  Yippie!

So what is likely happening is that each request is made and only two are being processed at a time, while the others will stack up in queue awaiting their turn.  But while their waiting, all the objects are being initialized, causing the memory to grow.  Eventually (if you had enough memory), you would start to see some timeouts occur from the failed requests that took too long to execute.

There are some freeware applications out there that were designed to screenscrape hundreds of requests.  I suggest grabbing some of their low level code and implement it in your app.  Here's a good place to start learning about sockets.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc300760.aspx

Comment: Hmmm that sounds reasonable but using ANTS memory profiler I can see that the actual managed memory stays on a very low level and doesn't grow. The problem is the allocated unmanaged memory which most likely grows insaneously due to the Bitmap/Graphics/GDI+ stuff I am using. Also, I can see in the logs that not a lot of web requests are made in parallel. It doesn't seem to be that 50+ web requests are pending.

Comment: My assumption is that if you use GDI+ within several threads there might be some GDI+ bug which doesn't release the graphic buffers because I read that the GDI+ .NET wrappers do have a lot of bugs which are also confirmed by Microsoft....

Comment: @Max - I thought about the image handlers as well, but didn't have to the code to confirm, so I'm taking a stab what I know to be true related to Parallel and using HttpWebRequest.  Your theory is quite plausable, you might try asking a new question and posting the source of your GDI+ code.

Comment: @Max - here's some additional food for thought... http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/parallelextensions/thread/d79e9f02-e48a-4085-84a3-15af1c6da2ca

Answer (score 1):

Parallel.ForEach is prone to start more threads than there are CPU cores. It can *appear* that memory is leaking because there are 50 threads or running.

You need to pause the debugger during the processing and see if there are too many threads running.